# What does "current leads voltage" mean?

Tags: capacitor, current

A [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071753214) I am reading has this sentence explaining capacitors:

> Capacitors are passive components in which **current leads voltage** by
>   nearly 90° over a wide range of frequencies.

I am not well-versed in electronics.  What does it mean for current to lead voltage?

Comment: IF you can imagine it , you can simulate it  http://tinyurl.com/rphfmnl

Comment: If you remember that you must charge a battery 1st before the voltage will rise then you will understand that a battery is like a massive capacitor like 10 thousand Farads and Current Leads Voltage on Caps

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Incredibly helpful, thank you!

Comment: If the book is describing it like that, it's *way* too advanced for where you currently are. It's talking about complex stuff like frequency response, when you don't understand the basics. You need a different book.

Comment: @Graham Thank you for your guidance.  I have a fascination with tube electronics and wanted to see if I could build something extremely simple involving tubes.  Still looking for such a project.

Comment: Has the book talked about [phasor-diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Phasor_diagrams) yet?

Comment: @Mast No, the book does not cover phasor-diagrams, although I had looked up that article on Wikipedia myself.  The book references 'phase shift', but does not define it.

Comment: @Sabuncu I'm sorry to be a killjoy, but tubes are very much not a mission for a beginner. I'd suggest getting the hang of op-amps first, and then try something more advanced. And apart from anything else, tubes tend to need fairly high voltages, so there's a safety issue too. The same principles from op-amps apply to tubes too, so it gives you a better starting point.

Comment: @Graham Good advice, thank you.  I will look into op-amps as you suggest.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Graham Do you have any further advice on learning electronics (I'm a software engineer).  How did you learn yourself?  I can build things with Arduino and Sparkfun, but I cannot design a circuit myself.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm a software engineer too, but I went to uni to do electronic and electrical engineering. The classic undergraduate textbook is *The art of electronics* by Horowitz and Hill, which is very good. If you need to start a bit further back though, I'd suggest looking up an AS-level textbook, which is probably a better kicking-off point.

Comment: @Graham Thanks. I have the Horowitz and Hill book, but I can't understand it.  AS-level: Advanced Subsidiary level.  Looked this up and it provided really good resources; e.g. https://resources.eduqas.co.uk/Pages/ResourceSingle.aspx?rIid=937 Thank you and happy holidays.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What it means is that compared to a resistor where current and voltage are in-phase, when the load is a capacitor then the current peaks (and inverse peaks etc) come earlier than the voltage peaks (and inverse peaks etc)

It doesn't necessarily mean that the current in the capacitor somehow causes the voltage, just that the peaks and troughs come earlier.

The current in the capacitor actually follows the slope of the voltage: it's positive when the voltage is rising , zero when the voltage is constant, and negative when the voltage is falling (ie. becoming more negative)

Comment: Why is this important? That is, why is this a thing? :)  Knowing this, how do designers design their circuits differently? Thank you.

Comment: thise feature is used in triac dimmers to control the firing angle of the triac,  as for its application in tube audio, thats hard to say.... in audio it's more use to consider capacitors as stopping DC current but passing AC (including audio signals) and as passing high frequencies better than low frequencies.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

Capacitors resist a change in voltage by consuming or sourcing current. So if you apply a voltage to a capacitor, you'll see that a lot of current flows in initially and then drops as the capacitor becomes charged to it's final voltage. Conversely since the voltage changes more slowly as the capacitor charges, the current will peak well before the voltage across the capacitor.

Answer (score 5):

This is a way of describing a positive or negative phase displacement.

[image]
([Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Voltage_with_leading_and_lagging_current.png))

A handy mnemonic is CIVIL

C IV  Capacitors: Current leads voltage

VI L  Inductors: Current lags voltage

Comment: Another mnemonic is " ELI the ICE man." For inductors (L) the E (voltage) leads the I (current.) For capacitors (C) the I leads the E. Hence, ELI the ICE man.

Answer (score 2):

If you compare the sine waves of voltage and current in an AC signal fed into a capacitor you will find that the waveform of the current is 90 degrees ahead of the wave form for the voltage.

[image]
Picture from wikipedia.